# ArcPy - SDE Connection Causes "pythonw.exe" Stops Working

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I came across this problem when tring to access some layers in the enterprise database (Oracle). The codes are written as:

```
cwd = sys.path[0]

# Process: Create Database Connection
DBConnFile_Name = "Enterprise.sde"
DBConnFile = os.path.join(cwd, DBConnFile_Name)

arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(
    cwd,
    DBConnFile_Name,
    "ORACLE",
    "<instance name here>",
    "DATABASE_AUTH",
    "<username here>",
    "<password here>",
    "SAVE_USERNAME",
    "",
    "SDE",
    "TRANSACTIONAL",
    "SDE.DEFAULT",
    ""
)

# Get the enterprise database layers
in_Council_Pg = os.path.join(DBConnFile, "DISTRICT_COUNCIL")
in_CrimePrev_Pg = os.path.join(DBConnFile, "DISTRICT_CRIME_PREVENT")
in_ZIP_Pg = os.path.join(DBConnFile, "ZIP")
in_Neighborhood_Pg = os.path.join(DBConnFile, "NEIGHBORHOOD")
```

I want to use those layers in enterprise database for further processing using other ArcPy functions. When I use the layers saved at local directory as arguments, the entire program runs perfectly fine. But when I try to use the layers in SDE as arguments, Windows tells me that "pythonw.exe has stopped working". One of the functions is written as:

```
# Process: Spatial Join - Council Districts
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(
    CrimeIncid_Pt_WGS,
    in_Council_Pg,
    CrimeIncid_Pt_Council,
    "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE",
    "KEEP_ALL",
    "",
    "WITHIN",
    "",
    ""
)

print "Stops here."
```

The programs fails at the function before printing "Stops here".

Do anybody have similar issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's failing on one of those 4 lines at the end?  Or is it after that?  Those 4 lines aren't actually doing anything (there's no connection to any files), it's just constructing a path variable.  Try putting those lines before the `arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management()` and see if/where it fails again

Comment: Thank you for replying, @Midavalo. I tried, but it still fails. There're functions afterwards use the path variables as arguments.

Comment: Where does it fail?  Try adding print statements after the 4 lines, eg `print in_Neighborhood_pg` etc. to show that they've created paths.  Or is it failing at the next functions?

Comment: I inserted print statement at multiple places and it fails at the first function uses one of those 4 variables as argument. The function is written as:

'arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(<input point layer>, in_Council_Pg, <output point layer>, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL", "", "WITHIN", "", "")'

Comment: Can you confirm that it passes the `print` statements and fails on the next function?  Please include that function in your code snippet as the issue may be related to that function

Comment: Please check the edited question. I hope it's clear enough for you to understand. Please ask me to add anything you might need. Thank you! And the typo you pointed out is just in this post, it's correctly entered in the program.

Comment: Try creating your SDE file in ArcCatalog and saving it to your `cwd` location, and removing the `arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management()` to test if the reason it's failing is due to an incorrect connection property somehow

Comment: It's still not working. I established and verified the connection again in ArcCatalog (I can see layers in database and I can add them to ArcMap), moved the SDE file from its default directory in C drive to my `cwd` folder, deleted the code creating SDE. But it's still not working.

Comment: Then the problem appears to be in your `arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis()` somehow.  Can you include actual tested code in your question for this tool?

Comment: I just changed the stuff in <> into the actual variables I used in my code. Hope that's what you need. Note that Spatial Join works fine with local Council District layer, it just doesn't love the layer from SDE.

Comment: Does the user you've created the connection for have CREATE table permission in your database?

Comment: Our database people says the user cannot create table so it won't establish join. I think this explains.

Comment: Yes, sounds like.  Try saving your join to a file geodatabase by changing just the output feature class and re-test the join works using the SDE connection.

Comment: Well, you've inspired me. It's actually not about the place of the join output - it's already in a local file geodatabase, but about where the place of input layer is. The enterprise database is preventing establishing the join from the beginning, because a joining layer is stored there, let alone the output layer. I tried a hard way to work around: copy the enterprise layer to local geodatabase, do the join using the copied layer and then delete the copy. It works, although it's not that elegant.

Comment: Glad it's worked.  Does the user have permissions to *read* that layer in the database?

Comment: Yes it can _read_. Thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: Instead of copying your enterprise gdb layer to the local database, try copying it to **[`in_memory`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm)** - this will be quicker and as it's only in memory there's no extra dataset you need to remove later.